# Error while installing node inspector on window 7 machine

Tags: node.js, npm, node-inspector

I ran following command to install node inspector.

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

But npm gave some error. Please see below image for more information. After this I ran `node-inspector` command which is not recognized by the system.

[image]

Comment: Somehow - Now I am able to download the package. Not sure if it was some problem on the server or  with my proxy. But its working now with the same command.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `npm` cannot download tarballs from the public registry.

The error message `ENOTFOUND` means the `npm` was not able to resolve the IP address of `registry.npmjs.org`. Check your network connection and DNS configuration and make sure you can access `registry.npmjs.org` (e.g. run `ping registry.npmjs.org`).

Comment: If I go to run prompt and type  `ping registry.npmjs.org` I get message saying `ping request could not find host registry.npmjs.org`. I typed `https://registry.npmjs.org/` in the address bar of the browser and I got this json back: {"db_name":"registry","doc_count":65961,"doc_del_count":379,"update_seq":71876,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":854741115,"data_size":269815409,"instance_start_time":"1395889664312215","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":71876}